# Using "ng-file-upload", can't upload file above, 15 MB (or partially upload)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I am using "ng-file-upload": "12.2.13", "angular": "1.4.7", "node": "6.9.0" and "npm": "3.10.8".

I imported a file of size > 20 MB and it did not show up. Then I tried 12 MB and it showed up. All files less than 12MB are uploaded correctly. All the file-import POST requests get a 200 response. But the location where the file saved shows no or partially uploaded files. I used resumeSizeUrl and resumeChunkSize = 10MB to upload in chunks. 
No issue with the nginx max file size upload, it has already increased (15MB). Not sure what is the issue; there are no logs in console or in the server side.

One possibility in my setup could be, our production has multiple portal instances that are round-robbined. So, one instance, might get the data and writes and then another instance gets the data and messes up. But not sure how to debug that. Could the ng-file-upload has a way to persist with a single instance when it sends the data every time? How it handles/sends data to multiple instances?

Here is the code snippet
{code}

```
    const url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;

    file.uplaod = Upload.upload({
      url: url + '/api-file-upload',
      data: { file: file },
      resumeSizeUrl: url + '/file-size,
      resumeSizeResponseReader: function (data) {
        return data.size;
      },
      resumeChunkSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
    });

    file.upload.progress(function (evt) {
     // upload progress
    });

    file.upload.catch(function (err) {
      //catch error;
    });
```

Here is nodejs code, 
A API to get the chuck file data

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api-file-upload',
    config: {
        payload: {
            maxBytes: 15728640,
            output: 'stream',
            parse: false
        },
    },
    handler: function (req, res) {
        const form = new multiparty.Form();
        form.parse(req.payload, function (err, fields, file) {});
    }
})
```

Comment: I debugged and noticed a few POST API gets 200 status code response in the console, but not sending the chunk data to the server. I print the request payload gets to import file API. What's causes it?

Comment: I got the issue and have found the workaround. The issue was with multiple instances I mentioned above. The changes were made with the nginx load balancing. I have disabled the load balancing for the '/api-file-upload' API. I have added a "location" in the nginx config for my API. Now it always uses a single assigned instance for the file upload API.